# How to programmatically check last Remote Desktop sessions for multiple servers?

Tags: windows, active-directory

In an environment consisting of an Active Directory domain and tens of different servers (Windows 2008, 2012, etc.).

**How can I programmatically list all recent logins (via Remote Desktop) to each of the servers separately?** How can I remotely query a server to list all the logins. What protocol/service/connection should I use to get that?

I would like to get something like:

```
 server1
 DOMAIN\john,2015-12-15 09:40
 DOMAIN\mary,2015-12-15 07:04
 DOMAIN\john,2015-12-15 03:33
 DOMAIN\john,2015-12-13 19:00

 server2
 DOMAIN\john,2015-11-10 05:04
 DOMAIN\someone,2015-10-09 15:12

 etc.
```

Comment: LogonType 10 is a RDP logon. How to query events for this activity was also asked here http://serverfault.com/questions/571732/filtering-security-logs-by-user-and-logon-type

Comment: ServerFault is not a script writing service.

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by the following powershell command

```
Get-RDUsersession | select ServerName, UserName, CreateTime
```

powershell.exe has to be run as local administrator on RDS-Server. (start powershell.exe as admin)

If you want to do this for all servers, the easiest way to do this is to find something similar. maybe they all have the same collection name or connection broker. if you don't have similarities, you'll need to work with `new-pssession` which can be kind of tricky.

```
Get-RDUsersession -collectionname RDS-SH-Collection | select ServerName, DomainName, UserName, CreateTime
```

to put this information out into a file write

```
$users = Get-RDUsersession -collectionname RDS-SH-Collection | select ServerName, DomainName, UserName, CreateTime | out-file C:\path\output.txt -force
```

Change all values (like RDS-SH-Collection or C:\path\output.txt) to your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check it using `qwinsta` (that is actually a [query session](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785434.aspx) alias) in a batch script like this:

```
qwinsta /server:server1
qwinsta /server:server2
```

And just add one line per additional server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please correct me, but from what I understand it lists all current sessions. And what I am after - is the history.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I interpreted "recent" as still ongoing, sorry